# WordPress Template Hierarchy for custom post types

Tags: wordpress, hierarchy, custom-post-type

Hi I have question about file names. If I have custom post type, and for template I can create fore example `single-portfolio.php` and and get content of portfolio posts into this file, but i need to get that post not in same file I want get it on individual files fore example `single-portfolio-post1.php` something like this but second file that I create doesn't work how can i do that?

Thank you

Comment: Is there any specific cause, for which you are not using the first one ?

Comment: yes for any posts I need to write special structure and design, and I can't use first one

Comment: If the structures are same and you need little changes , you can consider using your first template as template part for all other custom templates, that should work fine.

Comment: the structure is individual for every post :(

Comment: every post type is a different portfolio ?or every post type is different ?

Comment: on portfolio custom post type every post has different structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91608/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-aram-mkrtchyan).

Answer (score 0):

make single-portfolio.php

```
<?php
get_template_part('single-portfolio-post',get_the_ID());
?>
```

and now for say post with id = 3, make single-portfolio-post-3.php
and in this file do all your stuff meant for this post only